# How to use WinJS.Class.define() in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, winjs

To develop a Windows Store Application, how to use WinJS.Class.define() to define a class in Typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [MSDN article on TypeScript and WinJS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn201754.aspx) that covers the basics.

To use TypeScript with WinJS you need to include the [WinJS typings](http://typescript.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#typings/winjs.d.ts), which are on Codeplex.

This will give you auto-completion and type checking for your calls to WinJS library features.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use WinJS.Class if you use TypeScript. Just create a normal class e.g:

```
class Foo{
    bar = 123;
    doBar(){
        return this.bar;
    }
}
```

For other things inside WinJS you can use these TypeScript definitions : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/winjs/winjs.d.ts

Comment: Agreed. In case the original poster was strictly wanting an actual WinJS.Class, the answer is that you cannot use TypeScript to do that. Your options are to use a TypeScript class as @basarat has suggested, or to just type WinJS.Class.define(...) as you would in standard JavaScript. Either should work fine, but using a TypeScript class is the better option from a readability standpoint.